# How to get Mifare card version

Tags: smartcard, mifare

I want to detect the Mifare card type.
According to the NXP doc AN10834 Fig 3, I can detect the card type by sak number and Get Version.

My card's SAK is 0x20, but I want to know it is a DESFire or plus.

What is level 3 and level 4 Get Version?
Where can I get the information?
Any help?

Comment: What about AN10833, MIFARE type identification procedure (https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10833.pdf)